# How to orderBy across the entire table using Apache Flink Table API

Tags: apache-flink

In the following snippet, I am trying to sort my table by "value"; however, the sorting is only occurring within each partition, which seems to be the expected behaviour per the [documentation](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.8/dev/table/tableApi.html#overview--examples).

[image]

```
    Table result = aircraftsTable.join(flightsTable).where("tail_number = tailnum")
                .where("manufacturer === 'CESSNA'")
                .groupBy("manufacturer, model")
                .select("manufacturer + ' ' + model, manufacturer.count as value")
                .orderBy("value");
```

How do I orderBy across the entire table? I believe this is achieved in the DataSet API by setting parallism to 1; however, I don't see a similar function for the Table API in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are misreading the documentation, and it is saying that the sort is a global sort of the entire table.

But for what it's worth, you can set the parallelism on the ExecutionEnvironment just as you would for any other job using the DataSet API.

Comment: Ahhh I think it’s not globally sorting because I’m using version 1.4 and I think it’s a known bug that orderBy doesn’t work...

Comment: @david The order by function always runs with a parallelism of 1. I can't figure out how to sort it with anymore than that. I'm trying to pull messages from Avro files and sort them using the table API. I'm not sure how to process millions of messages using this table API. The whole thing is much simpler in spark.

Comment: A grouped sort can (and will if given the resources to do so) sort in parallel, but a global sort cannot.